# getting NullPointerException for inline code. I have defined the WebDriver globally, call browser method is working fine What i am doing wrong here

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
public class Test{
    static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Test2();
    }

    public static void CallBrowserChrome() {
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://google.com");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void Test2() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        CallBrowserChrome();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("G:\\Book1.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int rows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println(rows);
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            String value = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            System.out.println(value);
            **driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='js-main-container']"))
                    .sendKeys(value);**
        }
        }
}
```

//The Error is at this line Highlighted(driver in 2nd Class); I have tried giving the WebDriver inside the body of the method but that also does not work

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GzeA.png
```

Comment: remove the declaration from this line WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();. It should be driver = new ChromeDriver();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line: `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` declares the driver local to `CallBrowserChrome` and ignores your other declaration.

Change your first method to this:

```
   public static void CallBrowserChrome() {
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();// update this line
            driver.get("https://google.com");
            //...etc
```